How to set escape keyboard combination in GNU screen to CTRL+TAB?
How to set escape keyboard combination in GNU screen to CTRL+TAB?
Also, how to set keybindings to ALT+Left/Right for switching to next/previos tabs in screen?
I tried:
    escape ^|
    escape ^Tab
    escape ^[[27;5;9~
    bindkey ^[[1;3D prev 
    bindkey ^[[1;3C next

none of those worked.
